# При переводе плагина WordPress перевелась только админская часть, а фронт остался на английском

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Суть проблеммы в следующем: я делаю свой плагин для WordPress, и сейчас работаю над мультиязычностью.

Все фразы обернул в `__()` и `_e()`

Добавил `load_plugin_textdomain()` на хук `plugins_loaded`

Создал файлы .po и .mo

В настройках админки установил язык, на который перевожу.

И в настройках моего плагина для всех фраз перевод подтянулся, а для его фронтальной части (сайдбар) - нет. Все, как и прежде на оригинальном языке.

В чем может заключаться мое упущение? Спасибо.

Comment: Фронт смотрите залогиненным или нет?

Comment: Да, залогиненым.

Comment: Вы в настройках админки где язык установили? В профиле пользователя или в настройках сайта?

Comment: В настройках сайта.

Спасибо. Проблема была в неправильной логике работы плагина. Дело в том, что я слишком рано вызывал рендеринг html кода, и как я понимаю, мультиязычность срабатывала пост-фактум.

Изменил хук из plugins_init на wp_footer и все работает как надо.
`add_action('wp_footer', 'render_view');`

Еще раз спасибо, KAGG Design